# How to check whether grid view is fully scrolled or not

Tags: android

I have a question that "Can I check whether the GridView is fully Scrolled or Not through the Code?"

Comment: You may need to refer this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android