# How to get the contentoffset values of scrollview in android?

Tags: android

In iphone there are methods for getting the content offset values of a scrollview.

How can I implement this in android?

Are there any methods for getting the offset values of a scrollview in android?

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView already has method for it. [**See this for Detail**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32863117/3496570)

```
mRecyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset();
mRecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
```

And for other then RecyclerView use

```
targetScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int scrollX = targetScrollView.getScrollX();
            int scrollY = targetScrollView.getScrollY();
            Log.d(TAG, "scrollX: " + scrollX);
            Log.d(TAG, "scrollY: " + scrollY);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think padding is what you are looking for.

You can get them from ScrollView by calling getLayoutParams on it and use the getPadding...() functions of the LayoutParams class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getPaddingLeft%28%29

Comment: I wants to get the offset value, so that I can use that offset value for setting offset to another scrollview,so that I can change colors while scroling.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question: is this thread useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870546/synchronizing-two-horizontal-scroll-views-in-android ?