# RecyclerView - Smooth scroll to - show item as first

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView and I want to smooth scroll to position. When I use smoothScrollTo - it scrolls to that position - but it is not **first** visible.
Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. this is how to do it:

1. Get the current scroll. [here is how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507715/android-how-to-get-the-current-x-offset-of-recyclerview)
2. Calculate the offset of the item
3. Use: smoothScrollToXY(0,offset - currentScroll);