# Smooth scroll to top not working correctly on recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

When I am trying to smooth scroll to top element, mostly it gets stuck to 2nd or 3rd item. I am trying below code :

```
 recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: See those answers it solves the problem 
[First](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32819067/6177391) ,
[second](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33371563/6177391)

Comment: I tried answer First, it did not work for me :( .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after spending some hours I solved it myself. I don't know what's the logic behind this but setting

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(-10);
```

works for me. Now it always takes me to top element along with smooth scrolling.

Comment: perfect solution