# Horizontal RecyclerView in CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have made a view with horizontal `RecyclerView` in `CoordinatorLayout` such that the parent of `RecyclerView` is `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` . Everything works perfect except when we try scrolling vertically on the `recyclerView`. Is there a way we can scroll vertically while scrolling on Y axis and horizontally on X axis.

**EDIT**

There are two `RecyclerView` in fragment which is ultimately used in `CoordinatorLayout` . Now first `recyclerView` is horizontal and second is vertical. When I scroll horizontally on first `RecyclerView` it works perfectly and when I scroll vertically on second `RecyclerView` it works perfect. Now the problem is when I try to scroll vertically over first `RecyclerView` parent scroll should work.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't get what you want. According to your comment on @Harshad's answer, you want the recyclerview to be vertically scrollable while the row of the recyclerview is horizontally scrollable, is that correct?

Comment: Please go through the edit..

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is easy to do, checking scroll state of everyone RecycleView. 
So, as example, you have on one Fragment - 5 different orientation RecycleViews. And you want scroll all, when scroll some one from them.

1) Setup onScrollChangeListener on every RecycleView.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
    {
        mRecycle1.smoothScrollBy(dx, dy); // Or use any other behaviour 
        mRecycle2.smoothScrollBy(dx, dy); 
        mRecycle3.smoothScrollBy(dx, dy); 
        ......
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is works fine for any axes(X and Y). Check also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27546142/4133301) about RecycleView scrolling state.

Comment: not working in my case..onScrolled is called only when scrolled in x axis...not for y in horizontal RecyclerView.