# How to use Recycle.scrollTo?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView and when it is scrolled, other RecycleView needs to be scrolled programmatically too. I have implemented the following, where `recList` is a `RecycleView`. As you can see when X coordinate is queried, it is 419 value, but set 419 for an other `RecycleView` has no impact, other `RecycleView` is not moving. Why?

Why this line has no effect:

`recyclerView0.scrollTo(recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset(), 0);`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
((LinearLayoutManager)(recyclerView.getLayoutManager()))
    .scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, (-1)*recyclerView.computeHorizontalOffset());
```

Comment: That's really strange. This worked for me when I specified the pixels by which I wanted to offset the view from the start. Are you sure `recyclerView.computeHorizontalOffset()` returns the value you need? You can also try removing the `(-1)*`.

Comment: Yes returned value is valid, tried without (-1), and also changed x, y coordinates.

Comment: Are you sure your code shouldn't be in `onScrolled()` instead of `onScrollStateChanged()`?

Comment: You need to supply the *total scrolling offset from the 0th element* for this to work.

Comment: I do like the *total offset* approach. But `scrollTo` method has no effect, it is not shifting, only, `smoothScrollBy` but it accept difference value only. Should I infere from total, how much is the difference? but for that I need to store the initial position of the view .. complicate.

Comment: You could get the total offset by either keeping track yourself or by [using a library that does that already for you](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/ObservableRecyclerView.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try also to getting other scroll state. For me,  works perfect method:

```
RecycleView activeRecycleView;

// ......

for (RecycleView nextView : ViewHolder.getActiveRecycleViews()) {
    nextView.scrollTo(activeRecycleView.getScrollX, 0)
    // or.....
    nextView.smoothScrollTo(activeRecycleView.getScrollX, 0)
}
```

**Update:** Also please check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27546142/4133301)!

Comment: Funny with `smoothScrollTo` and `onScrolled` works, all the `nextView` are moving, but, they seem shifted onto different distances. `Recycleview`s are under each other, but they are not aligned. How is it possible? `dx` is always the same.

Comment: @János Based on Doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html "This method will always be invoked before listeners."  If you have several RecycleViews, Did they all scrolled with different distance?