# Event when scrolling is done

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-event, android-scroll

In a ScrollView (Vertical or Horizontal) how to know when the scroll animation is done?

I start the animation with smoothScrollBy or smoothScrollTo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to subclass `ScrollView` to use [`onScrollChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

See this other SO question:
[Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android)

Comment: But how I'll know what is the last event?

Comment: You could keep track of the last `smoothScrollBy` or `smoothScrollTo` "destination" and compare with the new ones in `onScrollChanged`.