# How to add items at top of ListView with scrolling without stuck?

Tags: android, listview, smooth-scrolling

I am working on chat application in which I have to manage thousands of chat messages list by paging but my problem is that when I am adding items at the top of `ListView` `adapter` during fast scrolling and applying `setSelectionFromTop(index, y)`...by this my `list` scrolling getting stuck on index...

```
 adapter.setData(listChatMessage);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 View v = threadList.getChildAt(0);
 int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

 listView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

So how can we add items at the top of `ListView` with scrolling without stuck. What approach should I use.

Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: please post appropriate code also

Comment: why don't you wait for the scrolling to be stopped before adding new data at top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I found satisfactory post.

https://chris.banes.me/2013/02/21/listview-keeping-position/

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong take look at this

[How to get the scroll speed on a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895504/how-to-get-the-scroll-speed-on-a-listview)

then set listView.fling(int velocityY)