# How to change an image depending upon ScrollView Direction (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scroll, scrollview

Basically I want to change an image depending upon whether the user is scrolling up or down in a Scrollview.

I know how to change an image dynamically but I can't figure out how to return the direction the Scrollview is currently moving.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android) will help you on implementing a scroll change listener. Using the value it provides, you can determine whether it is up or down.