# I want to put button on HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put button on **HorizontalScrollView** in android like **<< A B C >>** I have 10 textview like A B C D E...Left button must hide on Leftmost and Right button should hide when i am on last.

Comment: What do you already have? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to scroll when the buttons are clicked, or are they just to indicate the list continues?

If it's the second case, you could use an `OnScrollViewListener` to detect when the scroll has reached the limit. Check out this post for more information:

[Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android)