# how to synchronize scroll views simultaneously

Tags: android, scrollview

I used [Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android) to synchronize 2 scroll views . I this we implement an interface an

protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy); .

now can anybody tell me how to use this inteface or any other method for synchronizing four views simultaneously because onScrollChanged() in in-build method and use coordinate of only 2 scroll views. but I have to scroll 4 views. If there is any method please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can do something like

```
    if(scrollView == scrollView1) {
        scrollView2.scrollTo(x, y);
        scrollView3.scrollTo(x, y);
        scrollView4.scrollTo(x, y);
    } else if(scrollView == scrollView2) {
        scrollView1.scrollTo(x, y);
        scrollView3.scrollTo(x, y);
        scrollView4.scrollTo(x, y);
    } else if(scrollView == scrollView3) {
        scrollView1.scrollTo(x, y);
        scrollView2.scrollTo(x, y);
        scrollView4.scrollTo(x, y);
    } else if(scrollView == scrollView4) {
        scrollView1.scrollTo(x, y);
        scrollView2.scrollTo(x, y);
        scrollView3.scrollTo(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried This But It gives nullpointer exception on scrollview3. are there some modification done on Onscrollchanged Interface .Because that is responsible for scrolling.

Comment: and is scollView3 != null in onCreate?  Maybe you can first call the findViewById 4 times and next set the setScrollViewListener: this avoids that onScrollChanged is already called before scollView3/4 are created/initialized.

Comment: Thank You very much . that work fine. and make me to move forward