# Set content offset of ScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I am using a `ScrollView` which has multiple `LinearLayout`s  and more `LinearLayout`s get added as I scroll down to the end. I got this implementation from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android)

It works fine. But now the problem is when I reach the bottom of the `ScrollView`, it loads more contents and as I was scrolling just before new content got added, the `ScrollView` scrolls down further. I do not want this as it skips some of the things from my sight that I have not seen yet. What I want is that the `ScrollView` stops scrolling just before it loads more content. I suppose this can be achieved by setting the content offset of `ScrollView`. But I'm not able to find a way to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was so obvious but I overlooked it..
`ScrollView.scrollTo(int x, int y)`