# Google Maps Android API V2 blacking out part of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps Android API v2 into my Android Application. I'm placing the Google Map in the middle of my layout. It works great when the layout is able to fit on the screen, but when the layout is too big to fit, and the user scrolls down to see the rest of the content, the rest of the layout is blacked out by the Google Map. See the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

(Note: All the map gestures are disabled to allow the user to scroll.)

My layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/race_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14sp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/DetailsTop"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/race_in_chase" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/race_in_chase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/in_the_chase"
        android:textSize="@dimen/DetailsTop"
        android:background="@drawable/inthechase"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:paddingRight="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/race_name"
        style="@style/RaceDetailsName"
        android:layout_below="@id/race_num" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/race_track"
        style="@style/RaceDetailsText"
        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/race_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/race_time"
        style="@style/RaceDetailsText"
        android:layout_below="@id/race_track" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/race_tv"
        style="@style/RaceDetailsText"
        android:layout_below="@id/race_time" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@id/race_tv" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/race_track_size"
        style="@style/RaceDetailsText"
        android:layout_below="@id/map" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My map setup in my Activity:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private static final LatLng CHICAGOLAND = new LatLng(41.474856, -88.056928);

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(CHICAGOLAND)
        .zoom(14.5f)
        .bearing(53)
        .build();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

My hunch is the maps fragment does not like the ScrollView since the layout if fine if the entire layout fits on the screen and scrolling isn't required. The map itself appears to be the correct size. The blackout is the exact size of the remaining items in the view. Does anyone have any ideas how I can get rid of the blackout below the map so I can see the TextView below it? Everything I've tried until now hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around the issue with a hack. I extended ScrollView so I could get notified on scroll events. I used the ObservableScrollView implementation from [Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android).

I added to my onCreate():

```
ObservableScrollView sv = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
sv.setScrollViewListener(this);
```

Then, when I receive a scroll changed event, I toggle the visibility of the whole view, which forces a re-layout, which prevents the black box from appearing.

```
public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView sv, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    sv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I tried to invalidate() the map view, and toggling the visibility of just the map view, but neither worked. Thankfully toggling the visibility of the whole view doesn't cause any flicker or other strange behavior.

There probably is a better solution, but at this point, this is the only thing I've found that seems to work.

Comment: Really no flicker? I tried this solution with SlidngMenu, but the it didn't change anything. See this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419521/moving-mapfragment-surfaceview-causes-black-background-flickering/14571989#comment20335526_14571989

Comment: i have editTexts under map and i used this, the edit text next looses focus, how could i do that, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to adapt the above for the same issue in a Viewpager by overriding `onPageScrolled` in the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, 
                           int positionOffsetPixels) {
    if ((position == 0 && positionOffsetPixels > 0) ||
        (position == 1 && positionOffsetPixels == 0)) {
        MyFragment blackedOutFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":1");
        if (blackedOutFragment != null) {
            blackedOutFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            blackedOutFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Where position `0` in the Viewpager is a Fragment holding a MapFragment and position `1` is the Fragment getting blacked out after the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround: make use of the new [snapshot interface from GoogleMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback) and display a snapshot of the map while scrolling the page.

Here is my code to setting the snapshot (it's in the same fragment as map, called FragmentMap.java):

```
public void setSnapshot(int visibility) {
    switch(visibility) {
    case View.GONE:
        if(mapFragment.getView().getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            getMap().snapshot(new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap arg0) {
                    iv.setImageBitmap(arg0);
                }
            });
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        break;
    case View.VISIBLE:
        if(mapFragment.getView().getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Where "mapFragment" is my SupportedMapFragment and "iv" is an ImageView (make it match_parent).

And here I am controlling the scroll:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if(position == 0 && positionOffsetPixels > 0 || position == 1 && positionOffsetPixels > 0) {
                ((FragmentMap)adapter.getRegisteredFragment(1)).setSnapshot(View.GONE);
            } else if(position == 1 && positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
                ((FragmentMap)adapter.getRegisteredFragment(1)).setSnapshot(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {}
    });
```

My fragment with map (FragmentMap) is on position 1, so I need to controll the scroll from position 0 to 1 and from position 1 to 2 (the first if-clause). "getRegisteredFragment()" is a function in my custom FragmentPagerAdapter, in which I have a SparseArray(Fragment) called "registeredFragments".

So, whenever you scroll to or from your map, you always see a snapshot of it. This works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the MapFragment's height is 0 during the Activity's initialization . Try with

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20sp" >

....

      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/race_track_size"
            style="@style/RaceDetailsText"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I still have the black bar, and lint is throwing this warning: This RelativeLayout should use android:layout_height="wrap_content".  Any other ideas?

Comment: Just as an experiment - have you tried putting the TextView in question above the map fragment?  What happens when you do that?

Comment: I have tried moving the TextView. The black bar still appears below the map, but it's smaller since there is less layout (only layout padding/margins).

Answer (score 0):

Just an experiment, but have you tried adding the TextView to the screen programmatically in setupMap() after the Map has already been initialized?

```
// First, get a handle on the parent RelativeLayout, 
// call it parentRelativeLayout, then…                  

TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.MATCH_PARENT, 
    RelativeLayout.MATCH_PARENT
);
textLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);
textView.setLayoutParams(textLayout);

parentRelativeLayout.addView(textView)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it by making the surface view transparent

https://github.com/NyxDigital/NiceSupportMapFragment

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use the new GoogleMap.snapshot() function and using a screenshot of the map instead as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18212473/495800).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library,

https://github.com/NyxDigital/NiceSupportMapFragment/

This work fine for me.