# How to create buttons like Android Google Plus App

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I am new to Android development, and I am wondering if there are any samples available to create a panel similar to the photo/checkin/mood/write panel at the bottom of the google+ app on android.

1) Are they 4 buttons?  How do I style the buttons to look like that?

2) I want to auto hide the panel on scroll down, but show on scroll up.

Appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

Cheers

[image: Android Google Plus App]

Answer (score 0):

To show\hide panel - use [animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

This panel can be linearLayout with 4 buttons.

Do detect what've been scrolled look at: [Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can use linearlayout and in that take for imageview..when scrolling you can show/hide linearlayout..and for view you can use linearlayout color as black and this imageview images..

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I implemented exactly what you trying to do only without the buttons.

After lot of hours spending googling around I found this one - https://gist.github.com/imminent/4576886 by Dandre' Allison, which is a specific implantation of quick return bar for a list view which is little more trickier from other view components. For more implementations of quick return bar and other scrolling tricks you can use Roman Nurik's Scrolling Tricks library here https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt and here http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/scrolling-tricks/. I just saw that there is another quick return bar for list view implenation by Lars Werkman in https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView which I never tested. I used the Dandre' Allison snippet which works great.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question.

- all the buttons are either in ImageButton, or in ImageView that make it clickable. it's either you can lay it out in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, well it's depends on how you want to make it.

Answer (score -4):

Try  [Using split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) this will basically do the task for you.

Comment: not sure why this vote down but my answer is correct, for sample you can check http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html and then Demos Sample apk, check the Split Action Modes( sample in apk).

Comment: i think this vote, because the question was not "how to implement top action bar menu", but "panel similar to the photo/checkin/mood/write panel at the bottom of the google+ app on android" and actionbar provide the top menu.

Comment: yea, If we use split action bar then we can give similar effect and buttons will appear at bottom, its a part of action bar implementation.