# How to enable zoom in ScrollView?

Tags: android, textview, zooming, scrollview

**How to enable zoom in `Scrollview`?**

Here is an application that uses this function very well and works in API9 and more:

The `zoomcontrol` hide after 2 seconds without user interaction.

[image][image]

Comment: I guess this is actually a webview with html content, not a scrollview.

Comment: How I know if it is Webview? However, for Iphone it is possible to use, for Android it is impossible? I´d like to use scrollview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you are seeing **is a `WebView`** as mentioned by [Waza_Be](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327402/waza-be) in their comment.

If you want to implement something like this in Android, you can either use a `WebView` yourself and add text/images etc to this as HTML code. See [Building Apps In WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

If you absolutely have to use `ScrollView` you **will have to create your own custom implementation**.

You could have a `RelativeLayout` that contains the ScrollView and the two `Buttons` for zooming in and out. Have the `Buttons` in their own `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` and set this to align with the bottom right of the parent `RelativeLayout`.

That will give you the floating buttons above the `ScrollView`.

You can then detect a tap on the `ScrollView`, or when it scrolls using the example given in [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android) (`ScrollView` does not support an `OnScrollListener` as such).

When you detect a scroll/tap, you can then set the `Button` layout to be **visible**, and remove visibility after 2 seconds with a `Timer` or a `Thread` that sleeps for 2000ms.

To achieve zooming, you would have to increase the of the `TextView` font size for each **(+)** click and decrease it for every **(-)** click. For `Bitmaps` you could similarly scale the `Bitmap` to fill the new size.

A lot of work for what you want to achieve. Try to stick to `WebView` or find another way of representing your application.

Comment: I see, as you say, its gonna be hardwork to implements this with ScrollView, even more for complex layouts, I really think that's could be a great implementation, specially for old people, its also a great market, our programmers needs to think about exception people.