# Layout Cross scroll

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to construct the following layout logic:

[image]

1. Block C and Block B can srolled up and down, in this time Block A not scrolled;
2. Block A and Block B can srolled left and right, in this time Block C not scrolled;

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is:

1. Wrap content of Block A in HorizontalScrollView1
2. Wrap content of Block B in HorizontalScrollView2
3. Wrap content of Block C and Block B in LinearLayout
4. Wrap LinearLayout in ScrollView
5. Synchronize srolling of HorizontalScrollView1 and HorizontalScrollView2 like in 
   [Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android)

My xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.widget.ObservableHorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.widget.ObservableHorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/channel_layout"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <com.widget.ObservableHorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.widget.ObservableHorizontalScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```