# Android onTouch Listener Background Color Change

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm using onTouchListener to change the background color when the user's finger is down and change back to default when the user's finger is up. The problem is that when the user's finger is down the background color changes but if the user doesn't takes the finger up and starts scrolling the background color doesn't change to default. Please help.

Below is my code:

```
    V.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           switch(event.getAction()) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    V.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    V.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    break;
           }
        return true;
      }
   });
```

I've also tried to return false but the result is the same

Comment: you can try using the lowercase "v" in the case conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different approaches you can use.  You can look at MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and act when  you receive that in your onTouch.  You can look at MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE
and see if they have left the region your are checking.

You can also put a listener on your scroll View and change the background when it moves. [Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android)

Alternately, you could use a gestureListener and detect that.