# Android: 2 Synchronously Scrollable TableLayouts

Tags: android, scrollview, android-tablelayout

I created a TableLayout which is scrollable in all directions. To create a Fixed Header I created an extra TableLayout. Now I have 2 Scrollable TableLayouts.

But when I scroll 1 TableLayout the other TableLayout is not scrolling. How can I make them scroll synchronously?

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/container"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TwoDScrollView android:id="@+id/Scroll"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayoutHours"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:stretchColumns="0"/>

    </TwoDScrollView>

    <TwoDScrollView android:id="@+id/Scroll2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayoutLineUp"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:stretchColumns="0"/>

    </TwoDScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3952629/2310673) out..