# Synchronized two list scrolling

Tags: android

I have a problem with this topic:[Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android/3952629#3952629)

I am trying to understand this and it seems ok, but I do not understand how to declare this all work in XML file in this topic.

Please if you could show me the correct XML file. It is very important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to copy `ObservableScrollView` in your application package and after that in your xml file. Define it as with your package name like `com.<your package name>.ObservableScrollView`:

```
<"change to your package name".ObservableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    ... >

    ...

</"change to your package name".ObservableScrollView>
```

Comment: One more question....can this be done with FragmentList? Is it possible? I have looked in unimplemented methods and have not found any similar to onScrollChanged().

Comment: Yes, It can implemented with `Fragments` But i guess not with `FragmentList` as its scrollview explicitly.