# How to detect if an HorizontalScrollView is showing scroll bars or not

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have an HorizontalScrollView in my design, which I populate with a variable number of items. The problem I have is that sometimes I populate it with many items, so the ScrollView shows scroll bars. That's OK, but I would like to check this situation and show a Previous and Next buttons in this case.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think ScrollView has a scroll listener. [Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android) might help you for creating a custom one.