# Android stop scroll on certain position

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` that have a `LinearLayout` has a child. Also `LinearLayout` have 3 `ImageViews`.

When i do scroll i can scroll on whole 3 `ImageViews`. But **i want to limit scrollable area**. 
How i can do that?

```
-------------------------------
|                             |
|                            ||
|                            ||
|                            ||
|      SCROLL_VIEW            |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
-------scroll limit area-------
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
-------------------------------
```

> **Scroll view width & height = full screen**

Comment: do a custom ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a transparent view in the area where you want to avoid scroll
and in the ontouch listener of that view return true.

```
transparentView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });
```

> **If ScrollView on Full Screen**

Follow this - [Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android)

Comment: Also my scroll view is on full screen.

Comment: you dont want to add extra view ?

Comment: no. I want to manipulate a scroll position and reject scrolling when getScrollY() will be bigger that some value.

Comment: override on onscroll then write you own Custom Scrollview

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android

Comment: it might be a little hacky on many situations. Is there a more subtle way?