# Detect if a ScrollView is scrolling up or down - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-scrollview

I have one `ScrollView` with one `LinearLayout` with `TextView`s. I want to detect when `ScrollView` is scrolling up or down to hide/show `ActionBar`.

Comment: No direct way. Maybe this will help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to create a class that extends `ScrollView`

```
public class ExampleScrollView extends ScrollView
```

and then Override `onScrollChanged` that gives you the old and new scroll positions and from there you can detect which direction

```
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
```

Comment: Than I need to add my new ExampleScrollView  in xml file. Right?

Comment: yes with the full class path ie. `com.my.app.ExampleScrollView`

Comment: I get errors:
Custom view ExampleScrollView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work

Comment: well yeah you have to implement all the proper constructors

Answer (score 5):

I think I am little bit late to answer this but here is my answer

```
 scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            float y = 0;

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                if (scrollView.getScrollY() > y) {
                    Log.v("Message", "Scrolls Down");
                } else {
                    Log.v("Message", "Scrolls Up");
                }
                y = scrollView.getScrollY();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

check this out

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  float y0 = 0;
  float y1 = 0;

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
      y0 = motionEvent.getY();
      if (y1 - y0 > 0) {
        Log.i("Y", "+");
        AnimateFloat(true);
      } else if (y1 - y0 < 0) {
        Log.d("Y", "-");
        AnimateFloat(false);
      }
      y1 = motionEvent.getY();
    }

    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> A sure short answer

```
scroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {


                int x = scrollY - oldScrollY;
                if (x > 0) {
                    //scroll up
                } else if (x < 0) {
                    //scroll down
                } else {

                }

    }
});
```