# Hide the ActionBar when swiping up and show when swiping down

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hide, swipe

I seem to have an issue with hiding and showing the ActionBar.
My app starts with it hidden and I want it to appear back when the users swipes down on any part of the screen and hide it back then the user swipes up.

I have tried implementing this in the following ways:

**Method 1**: in `onCreate`

```
        View mView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        //mView.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;

        mView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);


        mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Swiped down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                        getSupportActionBar().show();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Swiped up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                        getSupportActionBar().hide();
                        return true;
                    default: return false;
                }
                //return false;
            }
        });
```

**Method 2**:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        switch (action) {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                Toast.makeText(context, "Swiped down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().show();
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                Toast.makeText(context, "Swiped up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }  
    }
```

Now here are the issues:

1. The function applies only on parts of the screens where I have no buttons or other elements which can be clickable;
2. Where it applies, it has nothing to do with swipes. It shows the bar as long as I keep the finger pressed on a non-clickable filed in the view.

**EDIT:**

With the replies from the comment, I managed to make the Action Bar show and hide based on scroll, but I still have the issue with #1, in which I cannot perform the action on any part of the screen.

It works only on the parts where `onClickListener` is not assessed.

Comment: seems like someone had this problem before. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297467/detect-if-a-scrollview-is-scrolling-up-or-down-android) thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if a ScrollView is scrolling up or down - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297467/detect-if-a-scrollview-is-scrolling-up-or-down-android)

Comment: This solved issue number two. But it does not solve the first one. I can only hide/show while moving on a small part of the screen. If I try this over my TextViews, it does nothing.

Comment: @alfalfa, heather: I managed to solve the second issue, but now onSingleClick and onFling  work at the same time and I want them to be exclusive. I have posted more details if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue after a few days of investigation. Seemed that the best choice was to implement a `GestureDetector` like this

```
    public class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private MainGame mainGame;

    MyGestureDetector(MainGame mainGame) {
        this.mainGame = mainGame;
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onDown");
            return super.onDown(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onSingleTapConfirmed");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onSingleTapUp");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onShowPress");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onDoubleTap");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onDoubleTapEvent");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onLongPress");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onScroll");
            if (e1.getY() < e2.getY()) {
                Log.d("Gesture", "Scroll Down");
            }
            if (e1.getY() > e1.getY()) {
                Log.d("Gesture", "Scroll Up");
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if (e1.getY() < e2.getY()) {
                Log.d("Gesture", "Swipe Down " + e1.getY() + " - " + e2.getY());
                mainGame.getSupportActionBar().hide();
            }
            if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {
                Log.d("Gesture", "Swipe Up" + e1.getY() + " - " + e2.getY());
                mainGame.getSupportActionBar().hide();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and implement it in my main activity as an `onTouch` with listeners for each part of the layout in my main activity.
In `onCreate`:

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mViewSelected = v;
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });

        gameScoreP1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        gameScoreP2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        fullNameP1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        fullNameP2.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

and the method to override the gestures:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (myGestureDetector.onSingleTapConfirmed(event)) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.fullNameP1:
                    diagUtils.changePlayerNameDialog(1, this);
                    return false;
                case R.id.fullNameP2:
                    diagUtils.changePlayerNameDialog(2, this);
                    return false;
                case R.id.gameScoreP1:
                    scoreSetter.manageGameSetPoints(1);
                    return false;
                case R.id.gameScoreP2:
                    scoreSetter.manageGameSetPoints(2);
                    return false;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        } else return true;
    }
```

Issue now is that when I perform the fling movement over a view like gameScoreP1 for example, it also detects the click. Is there any way to make these exclusive?

**EDIT**

Managed to solve the second issue as well by setting the views as clickable like such: `fullNameP1.setClickable(true)`