# Android ScrollView, check if currently scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-view, android-scrollview

Is there a way to check if a standard ScrollView is currently being scrolled?

Doesn't matter if the direction is upwards or downwards, i only need to check whether it's currently being scrolled at all.

Comment: Do you need [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) I think....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScrollView` in its current form does not provide a callback for detecting scroll events. There are two workarounds available:

**1.** Use a `ListView` and implement [`OnScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html).

**2.** Derive a custom class from the existing `ScrollView` implementation and [extend it to provide callbacks for scroll events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android/3952629#3952629).

Comment: Your first suggestion OnScrollListener works on ScrollView as well. Thanks!