# How to check whether scrollview / recyclerview is scrolling to up or down android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I am working on android app and using recyclerview and scrollview in some activities. Now I want to show some layout when recyclerview/scrollview scrolls in up direction and hide the layout when it scrolls in down direction.
I want a function which can tell that recyclerview/scrollview is scrolling in up or down direction.

Please help if anyone know how to do this for both recyclerview and scrollview.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: you can use OnScrollListener https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html

Comment: check out this: [Android ScrollView, check if currently scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28626671/3472667)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007135/3145960

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView scrolled UP/DOWN listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024058/recyclerview-scrolled-up-down-listener)

Answer (score 3):

> A sure short answer for this issue

```
scroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {


                    int x = scrollY - oldScrollY;
                    if (x > 0) {
                        //scroll up
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                       //scroll down
                    } else {

                    }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this way:

private static int firstVisibleInListview;

firstVisibleInListview = yourLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

In your scroll listener:

 public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
{
 super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

 int currentFirstVisible = yourLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

 if(currentFirstVisible > firstVisibleInListview)
   Log.i("RecyclerView scrolled: ", "scroll up!");
 else
   Log.i("RecyclerView scrolled: ", "scroll down!");  

 firstVisibleInListview = currentFirstVisible;

}
```

Comment: what if currentFirstVisible  == firstVisibleInListview and out item height is 200dp.