# Call scrollTo in onScrollChanged in Android HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, onscrollchanged

My application layout is like this:

[Please click to see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxUix.png)

the blue area is my content, 4096px. the red frame is a phone screen which is a HorizontalScrollView.

My layout is like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
  <ChartContent>
  </ChartContent>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

when the HorizontalScrollView (I will call it HSV for convenient) is scrolling to the end of the content area. I will make it scrollTo the beginning of the content area, and redraw chart in my content area. That will make the user feel it is like a endless scrollview.

I follow this post : [Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android). Inherit the horizontalScrollView class and override the onScrollChanged method so I can get the current x of the HSV.

Log like this:

it means the red frame is moving from left to right (oldx -> x)

```
onScrollChanged: 1006 -> 1180, speed = 174
onScrollChanged: 1006 -> 1180, speed = 174
onScrollChanged: 1180 -> 1254, speed = 74
onScrollChanged: 1180 -> 1254, speed = 74
onScrollChanged: 1254 -> 1325, speed = 71
onScrollChanged: 1254 -> 1325, speed = 71
onScrollChanged: 1325 -> 1366, speed = 41
onScrollChanged: 1325 -> 1366, speed = 41
onScrollChanged: 1366 -> 1406, speed = 40
onScrollChanged: 1366 -> 1406, speed = 40
onScrollChanged: 1406 -> 1449, speed = 43
onScrollChanged: 1406 -> 1449, speed = 43
onScrollChanged: 1449 -> 1499, speed = 50
onScrollChanged: 1449 -> 1499, speed = 50
onScrollChanged: 1499 -> 1518, speed = 19
onScrollChanged: 1499 -> 1518, speed = 19
onScrollChanged: 1518 -> 1544, speed = 26
```

but when I call scrollTo inside onScrollChanged:

```
call HSV.scrollTo(60)
```

Log:

```
onScrollChanged: 3708 -> 60, speed = -3648 —> ok
onScrollChanged: 3579 -> 60, speed = -3519 —> ok
onScrollChanged: 60 -> 3738, speed = 3678 —> wrong
onScrollChanged: 3738 -> 60, speed = -3678 —> wrong
onScrollChanged: 60 -> 60, speed = 0 —> wrong
```

the Line 3 - 5 is very confusing, and the HSV will suddenly stop at position x = 60.

Is there something wrong with my implementation? Or can I use other solution achieve my goal?